# Implement steepest descent on rosenbrock in python

Tags: python, math, scipy, gradient-descent

I'm trying implement the steepest descent method by the [algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUWYl.png)
with [step length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRacD.png):

and this is my code which can't converge and get overflow error, I think I calculate alpha wrong but couldn't figure out why.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen, rosen_der, rosen_hess

x = [-2, 2]
H = rosen_hess([0, 0])

g = rosen_der(x)
iter_count = 0
while np.linalg.norm(g) > 1e-10 and iter_count < 10000:
    alpha = (g @ g) / (g @ H @ g)
    x = x - alpha * g 
    g = rosen_der(x)
    iter_count =+ 1

print(x)
```

Comment: You don't increase your iterator correctly.
Write `iter_count += 1`.